# MySQL Enterpise Monitor - query analyzer - No data available in table - configuration

Tags: monitor, analyzer, mysql-5.1

I use `MySQL 5.1.69`

protocol_version    10

```
version 5.1.69-log
```

version_compile_os

```
redhat-linux-gnu
```

I have a problem with configuration/using MySQL ENTERPRISE MONITOR.
I don't see data in QUERY ANALYZER. (No data available in table).

[image]

I have a question - why this function is disabled?

My General Query Log is OFF, I'm not sure if it is required to use QUERY ANALYZER?

Is the version of MySQL important for this functionality?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix this?  I'm running into the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

this is due to performance schema is not enabled in 5.1 version.

By the performance schema only the query analyzer shows the result.

enable the performance schema

Answer (score 0):

You need at least MySQL 5.6 in order to use the performance_schema database (which does not exists before that). Consider migrating from 5.1 to a newer version of MySQL.

References :
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema.html